# Calculating the visibility of an observer walking a line transect

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, 3d-analyst, viewshed, visibility

I was wondering if anyone can help. I'm want to calculate the visibility for an observer doing a bird survey by walking 1km transects broken up into 200m sections.

I want to calculate the visibility for each transect using 6 points for each 200m section  so as to get as close to what a walking observer would be able to see as possible.

Originally I used a viewshed to do this and created a 250m buffer around each point then calculated the % area visible in each. However the problem is viewshed shows me what would be visible from at least one of the points and I want to know what would be visible from each point individually or atleast each set of 6 points that make up a 200m section. I have 320 200m sections in my survey so that's 1920 points which makes it impossible to do this by creating a separate viewshed for each point. Are there any alternative ways I can do this?

Comment: You've missed off one of the most basic bits of information for your question, what GIS system are you using?

Comment: Ah sorry, ArcMap10.

Comment: I suggest using an iterative process as Hornbydd describes, and/or using a `RADIUS2` attribute (set to 250) in your observation points to limit the distance of the viewshed. (The primary advantage of the latter is that it should limit the run time and speed up the process of 320 viewshed calculations!)

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using a model to automate this? You could use an iterator to step through each point and generate a view shed for it. Then if required merge the grids.  If you do not know what I am talking about its time for you to open up desktop help and start reading up on model builder. This will allow you to automate this task.

Comment: I've tried doing a 250m radius for my viewshed and now I want to iterate in model builder to calculate a zonal histogram for each of 320 buffers separately, so i can avoid the problem of overlapping buffers. However I've very new to model building and it doesn't seem to be working- I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've put my buffers feature layer into iterate feature selection, used the feature output to go into zonal histogram with my viewshed then used %name%zonalhist as the output from the zonal histogram to create separate tables for each buffer. The model runs but I get no output.

Comment: Sounds like you are doing it right. Make sure you do not have a selection on your input data, it may help if you upload an image of your model?

Answer (score 2):

You might consider using the **[Visibility Index](http://www.uoguelph.ca/~hydrogeo/Whitebox/Help/VisibilityIndex.html)**, which is a measure of the size of the viewshed for each pixel in a DEM. This way you could measure the overall visibility of a pathway or route. I wrote a blog on the calculation of the visibility index and some of the challenges involved that you might find useful here: http://whiteboxgeospatial.wordpress.com/2012/11/05/whitebox-and-landscape-visibility/

[image]

The software in which this index has been implemented is a free and open-source GIS called Whitebox Geospatial Analysis Tools (download [here](http://www.uoguelph.ca/~hydrogeo/Whitebox/download.shtml)) for which I am a developer. Here is an example, in which I have created a profile of the visibility index surface along a trail vector shapefile (yellow line overlaid on surface):

[image]

The y-axis of the profile is the visibility, measured as a proportion of the area of the DEM. Edge effects should be accounted for by providing a buffer area around the area of interest.

Comment: Great screenshots! My work may involve working with Visibility analysis in the near future so it is very interesting to see how it can be calculated and viewed. Already downloaded Whitebox so will give this a go myself!

Comment: @Joseph Great, let me know if you have any questions or feedback.

Comment: Interesting! I've already sorted out the problem here long hand doing lots of separate viewsheds but I'll definitely bare this in mind if I need to do it again sometime. Thanks!