# How to determine Visibility Map for Atmospheric Correction

Tags: remote-sensing, visibility, atmospheric-correction

As per Grass wiki: https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Atmospheric_correction 
the atmospheric correction could be done using a visibility raster in conjunction with an elevation raster. With regards to generating the visibility raster, I am trying to follow the stated methodology in ArcGIS (since there is no official methodology in Grass reference): 
[Viewshed for each pixel in raster?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/116392/viewshed-for-each-pixel-in-raster)
(I wouldv've liked to use the Grass r.viewshed tool to stay in the same platform but it seems, it does not allow multiple coordinates of viewing position. Is creating viewshed using ArcGIS is the right approach or is there any other methodology for generating Visibility map?

Comment: To help with one of your issues about multiple observer points, there's a grass add-on (python script) that takes a list of points and then generates a cumulative viewshed for them, see https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/addons/r.viewshed.cva.html

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE.  Please be sure to take the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour).  Your Question appears to have two questions; please **edit** it to contain one question.  You can leave out the "appreciation" parts, because they're more distraction than benefit.